# White borders on blurred video in background

Tags: html, css

I want to have a slightly blurred video in the background but there are for some reason white borders on the edge of the screen. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FieDV.png) of the bottom right side of the screen. How is it possible to remove those white borders?

The video doesn't have white borders if it isn't blurred. I've tried setting the widht and height to 110% but that didn't help.

```css
:root {
  --main-bg-color: coral;
  --menu: #D00000;
  --menu-hover: #FFBA08;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="background">
        <source src="background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this happens because the background bleeds into it. either set the background color of body or html to black or do the blur yourself in a canvas context. oh and trust me.. i feel your pain here..

Comment: you could also do some trickery with clip-path: polygon.. that's some hack tho.

Comment: a proof of concept i just started working on: https://share.home.gottz.de/2020/07/2020-07-06_13-37-57_image.mp4 css i use there: https://gist.github.com/GottZ/fd754ed91f2b0b1ff0562baf10f03cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this meets your use-case! This won't happen if you use `backdrop-filter` instead of `filter` - try putting an overlay over the video with `backdrop-filter` :)

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/annaazzam/pen/RwrMGVG

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```
<video>...</video>
<div id="overlay"/>
```